# Comma in series?

Tags: commas

How to use serial comma when list has commonality.

1).  I like the Mojave, Sonoran, and Colorado Deserts, and Sierra Nevada Mountains.

2).  I like the Mojave, Sonoran and Colorado Deserts, and Sierra Nevada Mountains.

3).  I like the Mojave, Sonoran, Colorado Deserts, and Sierra Nevada Mountains.

Which is the correct expression in USA?

Comment: [comma in a series. correct expression in the USA]. Not much point in fixing punctuation if the grammar is off....:)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either this (if you favor the Oxford comma):

I like the Mojave, Sonoran, and Colorado Deserts and the Sierra Nevada Mountains.

Or (if you don't):

I like the Mojave, Sonoran and Colorado Deserts and the Sierra Nevada Mountains.

An explanation of each comma, definite article, and coordinating conjunction would be pretty lengthy, so please ask if you have questions about any specific element.

Comment: One should not capitalize *deserts* and *mountains* there. Although the Mojave Desert and the Sonoran Desert are proper nouns, there is no such equivalent for any desert in Colorado. The other two North American deserts are properly the Chihuahuan Desert and the Great Basin Desert. The Colorado mountains are actually the Rocky Mountains if you need a proper noun,  or the various ranges like the Front Range of the Rockies or the Elk Mountains which are a small but unusual east-west running range that's also part of the Rockies, as all are here.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you, I wasn't aware of the terminology. My answer assumes that OP's proper nouns are correct. If what tchrist says is accurate, then please follow that advice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the two lists could be more clearly delineated with additional punctuation. I'd suggest:

I like the Mojave, Sonoran, and Colorado Deserts; and the Sierra Nevada Mountains.

Comment: Interesting. Although, I am interested in what others might say, I do like the idea of using a semicolon.  Thank you very much.  Also, if others reading this like the semicolon, please say so; i like the idea.

Comment: If your audience is familiar with these places, I think you can get away with just commas, but I would definitely keep the second *the* in front of *Sierra* These are connected by location and as wilderness areas, and are coequals. I find you can scramble the order and it still sounds fine. For instance, there isn't anything wrong with " I like the Mojave, the Sonora, the Sierra Nevadas,  and the Colorado Deserts." Of course, this assumes that you know the first two are deserts and the third are mountains. But I'm thoroughly familiar with all of them, this may not work for those who aren't.